# how to send an email from databricks notebook to outlook 2016 whenever stage fails in ADF

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I have multiple stages defined in my ADF , so if any stage fails I need to send an email to outlook 2016 saying particular stage has failed. How to achieve this using databricks notebook?

Comment: We use Logic Apps to do this from Data Factory. Here's an article describing the general process:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-send-email

Answer (score 0):

Use this article as an example on how to set up a Logic App. The Logic App will accept a few parameters like recipient, message, and subject:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-send-email

When you are done designing the Logic App, it basically acts like an EndPoint of an API, where you can call it as a URL and fill in the parameters as part of it.

In Data Factory, we then added a generic pipeline to send mails. It uses a simply web component that uses the URL from the Logic App, and uses a POST method.

The Body of the component will provide the values for the parameters in the Logic App:

```
{
   "message" : "@{pipeline().parameters.message}",
   "dataFactoryName" : "@{pipeline().DataFactory}", 
   "pipelineName" : "@{pipeline().Pipeline}", 
   "receiver" : "@{pipeline().parameters.receiver}"
}
```

In our master pipeline, we then are able to use conditional logic. If the step fails, it calls the mail component and sends a failure mail. If it succeeds, it goes to the next step. If that fails, it will use another instance of the mail component:

[image]

In total, we do this several times, using a separate mail implementation every time. This allows for custom messages per step, with custom recipients (depending on the step, you might need to send mails to specific groups).

It might be possible to reuse a single mail component, but in my experience, the conditions in Data Factory might not work exactly as you expect. We've had that happen to us, and so in order to be 100% sure things act the way we need, we chose to implement things in a bit more of a roundabout manner.